# Jekyll compile error

Tags: ruby, compilation, sass, jekyll

Jekyll does not seem to be compile my css once I initiate the following command in my terminal

```
jekyll serve --watch
```

This leaves me with pages that has no styles applied and just plain old markup

**Heres an image of my css located in the _site directory** (note no compiled css)

[image]

Once I save the main.scss file, the compilation takes places and my css is compiled and a quick refresh in my browser applies the styles. Shouldn't this happen straight away once i fire off the Jekyll server on my project?

[image]

**Versions**

```
 ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-darwin13.0.0]
 jekyll 2.5.2
```

**config file**

```
 # Site settings
 title: example
 email: your-email@domain.com
 description: > # this means to ignore newlines until "baseurl:"
 url: "http://yourdomain.com" # the base hostname & protocol for your site

 # Build settings
 markdown: kramdown

 sass:
  sass_dir: assets/css
  style: :nested
```

Comment: Can you show your `_config.yml` file ?

Comment: I was watching for a `baseurl` variable. I guess this is the problem. Can you give the `_includes/head.html` code ?

Comment: Yo Sam ! Your repository is quite uncompleted. No _includes, no _posts... You'de better start from a new jekyll and put it on the `gh-pages` branch.

Comment: i've added them back, but the same problem stil seems to occur @DavidJacquel

Comment: Sorry but what is your repository url ?

Comment: https://github.com/ssosina/sosina.me @DavidJacquel

Answer (score 0):

Right what I see in your master branch is a link to style sheet which is `/assets/css/main.css`. Served from you repository at `http://ssosina.github.io/sosina.me/` this resolve as a link to `http://ssosina.github.io/assets/css/main.css` Which miss is target.

I saw that you've changed it to `assets/css/main.css`. This is good for pages at the root of you site but will not work with posts or pages that are in a folder.

Eg: `http://ssosina.github.io/sosina.me/about/index.html` will point this link to `http://ssosina.github.io/sosina.me/about/assets/css/main.css` which again miss his target.

The definitive solution is to use `baseurl: "/sosina.me"` in `_config.yml` and to build your links like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/css/main.css" />
```

This will always point to yous css relative to the domain root, on any page.

**Edit**: When you set the `baseurl` variable, the `jekyll serve` command will serve your site accordingly. In your case, the command will output

```
Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/sosina.me/
```

Comment: hey, setting the base url brings up the following [problem](http://i.imgur.com/gpWPevM.png)

Comment: I also forgot to mention that this occurs when im working locally